# While trying to write numbers in excel sheet extra "00%" gets added automatically while saving the file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

When I am trying to write some numbers in a excel sheet they are shown right while debugging but after saving the file extra "00%" gets added to it and is shown in the output file.

errorSheet.Cells[rowNo, 1].Value = 1;
errorSheet.Cells[rowNo, 2].Value = 363;

Expected :
1           363
[image: Expected Output]

Actual output :
100%         36300%
[image: Actual Output]

The file might me corrupted. How can I resolve the issue, so that the file has correct output.

Comment: just check if you are not using any format explicitly like `errorSheet.Cells["rowNo, 2"].Style.Numberformat.Format ` or any other format related setting

Comment: @viveknuna Thank you ! After checking the number format it was "0%" and after changing it to "0" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
By placing an Apostrophe ( ' ) preceding the number

Sulution 2:
Format as Text Method

Comment: Thank you! The issue is resolved by placing Apostrophe ( ' ) or by changing the number format to "0%".